# How to run service every 30 mins forever using Firebase JobDispatcher?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

Till now, I have used AlarmManager to send HTTP request every 30 minutes. But recently, I faced warning in Google Play Console: Excessive Wakeups. When I read warning details, it said that AlarmManager waking devices up excessively.

Then I researched on what else I could use to send request every 30 minutes. In result, I found this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakeup.html). It recommends to use JobScheduler or JobDispatcher. First of all, I tried to use JobScheduler - but it required API 21 which is not okey for me. I need to support devices from API 16 in my current project. Then I decided to use JobDispatcher.

This is my JobService:

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("JobDispatcherLog", params.getTag()+ " STARTED");
        jobFinished(params, true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("JobDispatcherLog", params.getTag()+ " STOPPED");
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is where I am creating job which is supposed to run service every 30 minutes.

```
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher =
            new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));

    RetryStrategy retryStrategy =
            dispatcher.newRetryStrategy(
                    RetryStrategy.RETRY_POLICY_LINEAR, 1800, 86400);

    Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag("very-important-job")
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setRetryStrategy(retryStrategy)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
```

I tested this code and got following result in LogCat:

```
03-16 18:01:08.540 D/JobDispatcherLog: very-important-job STARTED 
03-16 18:43:41.747 D/JobDispatcherLog: very-important-job STARTED 
03-16 20:12:01.361 D/JobDispatcherLog: very-important-job STARTED
```

As you can see it is not running every 30 minutes.

My question: Is this normal behaviour for JobDispatcher? How to run service exactly every 30 minutes? If it is not possible, what else I can use to implement before stated function?

Comment: Alarm Manager as you have already mentioned if you want tasks to run at certain exact times like a calendar event. But if you don't need tasks to run at exact event job scheduler is the way.

Comment: Note the time window you specified was on the retry - which applies on failed job and denotes the initial and final backoff times.  Probably not what you were intending.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the time window in which your job could be triggered. It can help you to control a little the time margin in which your job must trigger.

```
        // Create a new FirebaseJobDispatcher with the driver
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

        // Building the Job.
        Job yourJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(YourJobService.class)           // The Job service that will execute.
                .setTag(YOUR_JOB_TAG)                       // Unique Tag.
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)              // To make it last "forever".
                .setRecurring(true)                         // To make it repetitive
                /* setTrigger is your time window. You can adjust the SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS to reduce the window a little. But it is not guaranteed to be .*/  
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(ALARM_INTERVAL_SECONDS, ALARM_INTERVAL_SECONDS + SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS))             
                .setReplaceCurrent(true) // To make it to overwrite a previous job created with the same tag.
                .build();
```

**NOTE:** Be aware that if your are going to use FirejobDispatcher (or JobScheduler) then there will not be guarantees that your service will trigger exactly each 30 min.

If you want a more precise "alarm" then you must incline in using AlarmManager + Foreground Service. Be aware that AlarmManager for Android 6 or later will have a little delay (in other words the alarm will not trigger in exactly 30 minutes).